# inject multiple values using provider to my service constructor - angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

How can inject multiple values to my service if I have constructor like this

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('name') @Optional() public name?: string) {            
}
```

and inside AppModule I tried following

```
...
providers: [
    SecurityService, providers:[
      {  provide: 'username', useValue: ''  },
      {  provide: 'http', useValue: Http  }
    ],
..
```

but I'm getting syntax error in line `SecurityService, providers:[`

```
Cannot find name providers
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass in the dependencies as an array (you don't need to destructure it):

```
...
providers: [
    SecurityService, 
    [
      {  provide: 'username', useValue: ''  },
      {  provide: 'http', useValue: Http  }
    ],
...
```

Or go ahead and destructure it for the sake of cleaner code:

```
...
providers: [
    SecurityService, 
    {  provide: 'username', useValue: ''  },
    {  provide: 'http', useValue: Http  }
...
```

Comment: Thank you, now I realize that I cannot use this simple http to inject Http. Any ideas on that?